# Enforcing primary key constraint in Spring JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, derby

I am using Spring JPA backed by an embedded in-memory database, specifically Apache Derby.

Simply put, I have an entity class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false, name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    } 
    //continue....
```

and in a @Service component I have a method like this:

```
@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;

@Override
public void addPerson(Person person)  {
        personRepository.save(movie);
}
```

where the repository is defined as follows:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> { }
```

The **problem** is the following: the primary key constraint is not enforced as I would expect.

More specifically, If I have two Person object with the same key:

```
Person person1 = new Person(1L, "Johan");
Person person2 = new Person(1L, "Tom");
```

and I call in sequence the add method:

```
serviceObject.addPerson(person1);
serviceObject.addPerson(person2);
```

what will happen is that the *personRepository.save(movie)* method is going to save a Person with same ID twice, thus overwriting the former record. In the end there is only one Person with that ID, and its name is "Tom". I retrieve a record using the *findOne* method as follows:

```
public Person getPersonById(long personId) {
    Person person = personRepository.findOne(personId);
```

However I would have expected the second attempt to fail because of some PrimaryKey Constraint Violation, with the name not being changed from "Johan" to "Tom".

**Questions**:

- Why this is happening?
- I understand that I could have enforced this rule at the database level. Is this the only way to achieve it? In my case, using Apache Derby, can I achieve this? Or how to enforce at the JPA level the usual primary key constraint so that records with a duplicate key are rejected rather than overwriting the previous one?

P.S.: I am interested into inserting the primary key manually, so *@GeneratedValue* or any other mechanism that would prevent in principle to pass twice the same key are not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation on save method,

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

it is trying to merge if the record already exists. In your case leave the generation of primary key to spring and use the generated id in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In spring data jpa, when saving a none managed entity with a non auto generated id , jpa will look for the id, if the id exists in the database it will treat save as update, so you are just updating your record

Comment: by persistence context you mean a real database which enforces the constraints?

Comment: so the only way to achieve it is placing that rule at the database level?

Comment: no persistence context is an in memory storage like a cache

Comment: why your id is not auto generated?

Comment: for some practical reason I need the client being able to choose the ID on his own

Comment: In this case you can add and Id for the user and put a unique constraint for that, but leave the generation of the id for the jpa.